# Get data from Azure Table on Android App using Shared Access Signature

Tags: android, azure-storage, azure-mobile-services

I need to get data from Azure Table on my Android app.

I have been provided with

1) Shared access signature (looks like :: `?sv=XXX&tn=XXX&si=XXX&sig=XXX`)

2) URI (looks like [this](https://XXX.table.core.windows.net)).

3) Partition Key

and information that `Row key`(Integer) is the version of data and `Row Value` is a `JSON` `String`.

I need to get the latest version of this `JSON` `String` on Android App.
I am also unaware if the information provided to me is sufficient.

I searched the web and found a relevant example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn246929.aspx). But I am unable to make it work. It returns a `null` Entity.

I know just the theory of Azure Tables and have not used it earlier. I also can't create an account on Microsoft for practice, since it needs Credit Card details for verification and I don't have one.

Comment: Are you using the Mobile Services product at all? Or are you just trying to work with Table Storage directly from Android?

Comment: You need Azure to use Azure Table storage. You could try using the Storage Emulator (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff683674.aspx), but I'm not sure how easy it is to use with an Android device or emulator.

Comment: @mattchenderson, I don't have any access to the account on which this table is stored, so I can't create a mobile service. I'll have to work with  Table Storage directly I guess..

Comment: Answer to this question solved my problem :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28689250/how-to-get-data-from-azure-db-table-to-an-android-app.

Comment: There's also an [Android library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-android) for Azure Storage.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Azure Storage Android library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-android). A tutorial on using Azure Tables is [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-java-how-to-use-table-storage/). Since you only have a shared access signature (SAS) token rather than the account name and key, you should append the SAS token to the URI and use appropriate table constructor to make a table instance to work on.

Comment: I have account name and SAS url. But dont know how to use it in code. I have refer the demo given by the Azure for storage library. But in that demo, they have not given way to use SAS to upload file. Can you please explain it with updating your answer?

Comment: One more thing, I dont have key. My client has not given me key to access it. because it is possible to use without key.