# Outlook API Android service Rest

Tags: android, json, api, azure, outlook

I'm beginner in android development and i want to create an app which have a database in Microsoft Azure and i want to recover data from the database to Outlook agenda (many users and many meeting).
Could you please advice me how to do?
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Get data from Azure DB Table to an Android app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28689250/how-to-get-data-from-azure-db-table-to-an-android-app)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I need to get data from Azure DB table to my agenda outlook which i have to integrate in my android app?

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the Mobile Apps services on Azure, and connect to your Azure SQL database, then you can easily receive and sync data from Azure SQL database with Mobile Apps Android SDK. Please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-android-get-started/ for more info.

On the other hand, you can integrate the graph rest api to implement the functionality of recovering data to outlook, refer to https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/calendar for details.

Additionally, to integrate graph rest api in Android, you can leverage the client SDK, please refer to https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-android for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.